# Update joinable() before closuer join() thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

How to manage thread like this:

```
thread th(foo);

while(th.joinable())
{
  // thread foo is active;
  // some printing from foo function for example
}

th.join();
```

This `while` is infinite because th.joinable() is always true and not updating. What reason and how to solve this problem?

Comment: See the definition in e.g. [this `joinable` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joachim pointed out, joinable() is true as long the thread is not already joined (or default constructed).

As I understand your requirements (from your comments), you may just call th.join() without the while-loop. This blocks until foo is finished.

Comment: My function foo() changes value of some static variable. This variable i have to print while thread is active, but i can't understand how to find yout from main() is thread still active or already finished.

Comment: In this case you should use a (boolean) flag that indicates if the thread is still running. Set it to true int hte main thread before starting the worker thread and reset it in the worker thread function as last command.